# Eclipse and Pydev - how to edit syntax coloring choices

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I've really looked everywhere for a lead on this.

I'm using Eclipse (Kepler) and Pydev 4.0.0.

The default syntax coloring for Pydev is driving me crazy. But what's driving me more crazy is that I cannot find an obvious source that explains how to adjust syntax coloring.

In specific, what I want to do is simply adjust the color used for # comments. Right now it's a very pale gray on white, and almost invisible to me.

It's easy to see how you can monkey with colors for Java editors, but for editing Python, it just seems that I'm stuck with the hardcoded syntax color choices.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Coloring in eclipse is tricky but it can be done:
windows -> preferences -> pydev -> editor ...scroll down in inset box to "comments"

Good luck!

Comment: ...thanks so much!  It turns out that in Kepler, the path for me was: Eclipse -> Preferences -> Pydev -> Editor ...and then scroll down in the box to find Comments.  It helped a lot to know that there is indeed a place to configure this and that it could be located with a little poking around. Good hunting!

Comment: For Eclipse 20190314-1200, there is no "Comments" in the inset box. There is "Block Comments", so that must be it. I don't see anyway to change other syntax coloring.

Answer (score 4):

Windows->preference->Editor when clicking editor Appearance table appear click on comment then change the color as shown in pic:

[image: change comment color in eclipse]

Comment: I had to close and reopen Eclipse for the change to take place.  Version 2020-09 (4.17.0), running in WSL Ubuntu